# Avoid collapsing several messages into one with node.js winston + logstash

Tags: node.js, logstash, winston

### In node.js, having set up winston and logstash...

I observe in the logstash user-interface (Kibana) that oftentimes several logging messages are tucked into one row as if they are a single message. Any quick shot at which component is causing this and how it can be avoided?

although message groups could be nice in general.... the messages are collapsed quite arbitrarily and it is detrimental - as the message structure of such a group is different than a regular message, which really doesn't help mining the data.

Hopefully the transport sends over chunks to save on communication overheads, but I would very much like that each message emitted by my code to winston, remains a single message and does not get grouped with other ones.

(I am currently [using winston-logstash](https://github.com/jaakkos/winston-logstash) for funneling from winston to logstash).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the logstash split filter avoids this. Poor documentation BTW.